# Writing a PNG using zlib

Tags: png, zlib

I am trying to write a PNG using zlib directly. However, the output file is not correct. Looking at it in frhed, the IDAT chunk shows periodic patterns and a large block of zeros. This indicates that something is wrong when calling zlib. Here's the code:

```
#include "FrameGrabber.h"
#include "Image.h"
#include "crc.h"
#include <zlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>



template<class T>
void assign(void* addr,T x)
{
T* p_out= (T*)addr ;
*p_out=x;
}

inline int32_t swap_bytes(int32_t x)
{
asm("bswap %1":"=r"(x):"r"(x):);
return x;
}

//Input is BGRx (convert to BGR (should be swapped to RGB later) and add a byte in the beginning)
void filterApply(const unsigned char* const* scanlines,char* buffer_png,int width,int height)
{
for(int k=0;k<height;++k)
    {
    *buffer_png=0;
    ++buffer_png;
    for(int l=0;l<width;++l)
        {
        assign(buffer_png,( (int32_t*)(scanlines[k])  )[l] );
        buffer_png+=3;
        }
    }
}

size_t compress(const char* buffer_uncompressed,char* buffer_compressed,size_t length_in)
{
z_stream stream;
memset(&stream,0,sizeof(stream));
//  15 bits=32K?
deflateInit2(&stream,6,Z_DEFLATED,15,9,Z_FILTERED);

stream.avail_in=length_in;
stream.next_in=(unsigned char*)buffer_uncompressed;
stream.avail_out=length_in;
stream.next_out =(unsigned char*)buffer_compressed;
do
    {       
    deflate(&stream, Z_FINISH);
    }
while (stream.avail_out == 0);
deflateEnd(&stream);
return stream.total_out;
}



const size_t CHUNK_BASE_SIZE=12;

void Chunk_sizeSet(char* chunk,uint32_t size)
{assign(chunk,swap_bytes(size));}

void Chunk_IDSet(char* chunk,uint32_t id)
{assign(chunk+4,swap_bytes(id));}

void Chunk_CRCSet(char* chunk,const PngCRC& crc,uint32_t size_chunk_data)
{assign(chunk+8+size_chunk_data, swap_bytes(crc(chunk+4,size_chunk_data+4)) );}



const size_t IHDR_SIZE=13;
const int IHDR_COLORTYPE_RGB=2;

void IHDR_widthSet(char* chunk,int32_t width)
{assign(chunk+8,swap_bytes(width));}

void IHDR_heightSet(char* chunk,int32_t height)
{assign(chunk+12,swap_bytes(height));}

void IHDR_bitDepthSet(char* chunk,char bd)
{chunk[16]=bd;}

void IHDR_colorTypeSet(char* chunk,char ct)
{chunk[17]=ct;}

void IHDR_compressionMethodSet(char* chunk,char cmprm)
{chunk[18]=cmprm;}

void IHDR_filterMethodSet(char* chunk,char filter)
{chunk[19]=filter;}

void IHDR_interlaceMethodSet(char* chunk,char interlace)
{chunk[20]=interlace;}



int main()
{
PngCRC crc;                              //The CRC code works
char signature[8]={137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10};

char IEND[CHUNK_BASE_SIZE];
Chunk_sizeSet(IEND,0);
Chunk_IDSet(IEND,0x49454e44);
Chunk_CRCSet(IEND,crc,0);

FrameGrabber grabber(GetDesktopWindow()); //Grab the desktop (works)
Image img(grabber);
grabber.grab();

char IHDR[CHUNK_BASE_SIZE+IHDR_SIZE];
Chunk_sizeSet(IHDR,CHUNK_BASE_SIZE+IHDR_SIZE);
Chunk_IDSet(IHDR,0x49484452);
IHDR_widthSet(IHDR,grabber.widthGet());
IHDR_heightSet(IHDR,grabber.heightGet());
IHDR_bitDepthSet(IHDR,8);
IHDR_colorTypeSet(IHDR,IHDR_COLORTYPE_RGB);
IHDR_compressionMethodSet(IHDR,0);
IHDR_filterMethodSet(IHDR,0);
IHDR_interlaceMethodSet(IHDR,0);
Chunk_CRCSet(IHDR,crc,IHDR_SIZE);   


size_t size_uncompressed=(1+3*grabber.widthGet())*grabber.heightGet();
char* img_png_uncompressed=(char*)malloc(size_uncompressed);
filterApply(img.rowsGet(),img_png_uncompressed,grabber.widthGet(),grabber.heightGet());

    //The compressed chunk should not be larger than the uncompressed one.
char* IDAT=(char*)malloc(size_uncompressed+CHUNK_BASE_SIZE);

int32_t size_idat=compress(img_png_uncompressed,IDAT+CHUNK_BASE_SIZE,size_uncompressed);
Chunk_sizeSet(IDAT,size_idat);
Chunk_IDSet(IDAT,0x49444154);
Chunk_CRCSet(IDAT,crc,size_idat);


FILE* file_out=fopen("test.png","wb");

fwrite(signature,1,sizeof(signature),file_out);
fwrite(IHDR,1,sizeof(IHDR),file_out);
fwrite(IDAT,1,size_idat,file_out);
fwrite(IEND,1,sizeof(IEND),file_out);
free(IDAT);
fclose(file_out);

return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Found a bug in filterApply. Now i do not get any large empty blocks but the file is still invalid. It just affects input data so it is correct.

Comment: You should just use libpng (http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).  It was written to encode and decode png files efficiently and support all png options.  It of course uses zlib.

Comment: Support for all options will degrade performance.

Comment: That doesn't make it slower.  libpng has been optimized over years, so its probably faster than what you might write in a day.  It just means a little more code linked in that you won't use.  It adds a few hundred K bytes to your executable.  You don't have enough memory to support that?

Comment: The problem is that I cannot reuse the settings and image buffers when writing next image. I will write thousands of images with the same width, height and bit depth and it is not fun to say png_create_write_struct every time (25 times per second). Also virtual calls required by customization (i write each frame to a memory buffer rather than a file allowing better parallellisation) are a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, just use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) and you won't have to worry about any of this.

You are setting the chunk size incorrectly.  The chunk size does not include the length, chunk id, or crc.  You are also calculating the crc incorrectly, with respect to what it is calculated over.  And you're writing the compressed data to the wrong place int the IDAT chunk.  I'll stop there -- you need to read the [PNG specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Contents.html) much more carefully.

**Other comments:**

I'm not sure what `crc.h` is, but zlib already provides the `crc32()` function which is compatible with png.  It is possible that the `crc()` routine you are using from `crc.h` is computing a different crc.  Even if it's the same crc, `crc32()` already being linked in by zlib, so you might as well use it.

You shouldn't use the name `compress()` since that function is already provided by zlib.  Since you're using zlib, the use of a `compress()` function that's different would confuse the reader.

The `while (stream.avail_out == 0);` makes no sense.  Either the first call of `deflate()` completes with `avail_out != 0`, or it gets stuck in an infinite loop, since calling deflate() again won't change that.

If you want to use `Z_FINISH`, then you need to use `deflateBound()` to set the size of the output buffer to guarantee that it completes.  The comment in the source code "The compressed chunk should not be larger than the uncompressed one." is not guaranteed.  Incompressible data will result in the compressed data slightly larger than the uncompressed input.

You're not checking any return codes from the `deflate` functions!  Check the return codes.

Comment: *libpng is too much
*crc.h contains the crc algorithm suggested by the png specification
*Did you ever read about static polymorfism in C++?
*And for the rest, I need a simple understandable compression loop that works. What about the 32K spec?

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking with "What about the 32K spec?".

Comment: "For PNG compression method 0, the zlib compression method/flags code must specify method code 8 ("deflate" compression) and an LZ77 window size of not more than 32K."

Comment: A sliding window size of 32K is the maximum size for the deflate format, and is the default in zlib.  The `15` in your `deflateInit2()` call is what specifies the 32K window.

Comment: I had some boring alignment issues in assign. Also some offsets wrong yes.